# Function tending to $-\infty$ tends to $+\infty$ in picture given by Plot

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have problems with this function $f(x) = e^{-x}+\ln(x+5\pi)$.

I computed the following limit by hand: $\lim\limits_{x\to-5\pi^+} f(x)=-\infty$, which I think is correct.

But when I plot this function in Mathematica with the next command:

```
Plot[Exp[-x] + Log[x + 5*Pi], {x, -5*Pi, 0}]
```

I get the following:

[image: plot]

What am I missing here ?

Edit: Also using the limit command gives the right answer to the limit I wrote ($-\infty$), but plot still looks to be wrong. :

```
Limit[Exp[-x] + Log[x + 5*Pi], x -> -5*Pi, Direction -> 1]
```

Comment: Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag unless another user has confirmed that what you observe is indeed a bug.

Comment: I think not, because $Dom(f) = \] -5\pi, \ infty\[$

Comment: You had limit -Infinity first before editing the question.. So I removed the comment. Mathematica says `Limit[Exp[-x]+Log[x+5*Pi],x->-Infinity]` is `+Infinity`

Comment: I see your point. Still can't figure out what is going wrong here. Maybe Mathematica is taking it as a complex number ?

Comment: Try the following and you'll know what's wrong: `{Exp[5. Pi], Log[10.^(-10^6)], Log[10.^(-10^7)]}`. The visualization with `Plot` remains a challenge though.

Answer (score 10):

The exponential function is just really large at at $-5\pi$ and the logarithm goes slowly towards $-\infty$ at $-5\pi$. It's really only a Problem of how to display that properly.

Let's plot the function before the singularity properly.

```
Plot[Exp[-x] + Log[x + 5*Pi], {x, -5*Pi, -5*Pi + 10^-8}, PlotPoints -> 200, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

If you look close enough before the singularity you can see that it does indeed tend towards $-\infty$.

**Edit**

To give an idea of how excruciatingly slow the logarithm goes to $-\infty$ look at

```
Table[{-i, Log[10^-i]}, {i, 0, 20}] // N // TableForm
```

[image: Log]

We're already at $10^{-20}$ and yet the logarithm has only fallen to -46. A drop of -46 cannot really be seen when your x range is $0$ to $15.7$ and your y rang is $0$ to $10^{6}$

Comment: Nice job there. I'm starting to understand what was going on there. It's really something to be aware of !

Comment: I might be wrong but I think something similar happens when trying to plot the derivative of this funcion. This one doesn't contain any logarithm so far since $f'(x)=-e^{-x}+\frac{1}{x+5\pi}$

Comment: @joeren While the two cases are similar in nature I would argue that the logarithm exhibits much slower convergence towards $-\infty$. Infact the logarithm does not only grow slower towards $-\infty$ than $1/x$ but also slower than the square root of $1/x$ or its cube root and so on. To make this mathematically precise $\log(x+5\pi)=\mathcal{o}(1/(x+5\pi)^n), a\to -5\pi$ for any $n \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Answer (score 3):

[Max1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13651/max1) has already given the correct answer. Here I just want to show a possible way to visualize when $f(x)$ becomes negative:

```
data = Table[With[{x = -5Pi + 10^(-10^k)}, {k, Exp[-x] + Log[x + 5 Pi]} // N[#, 16]&], 
             {k, 1, 8, 1/10}];

ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange->All, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None},
             Ticks -> {{#, -5 Pi + 10^-Superscript[10, #]}&/@Range[8], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some observations

```
Plot[Exp[-x] + Log[x + 5*Pi], {x, -6*Pi, -4 Pi},
 PlotRange -> {{-6 Pi, -4 Pi}, All}, Exclusions ->None,
 PlotPoints -> {100, {-5 Pi}}, 
 Ticks -> {{-6 Pi, -5 Pi, -4 Pi}, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Below $-5 \pi$ it is complex valued, so one gets blank plot for `x<-5 Pi`, at exactly $-5 \pi$ it is $-\infty$ (singularity) and above $-5 \pi$ it is real and large value.

The above plot seems to me to reflect this.

```
data = Table[{x, N[Exp[-x] + Log[x + 5*Pi]]}, {x, -6 Pi, -4 Pi, Pi/10}];
MatrixForm[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I wanted to see how Maple handles this hard plot:

```
restart;
plot(exp(-x)+ln(x+5*Pi),x=-6*Pi..-4*Pi)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Humm... maybe I should send a bug report to Maple on this :) This really looks very strange result.

Comment: It looks even weider there. Anyway, as Max1 pointed out, by plotting points really (really) close to the singularity the correct tendency (-Infinity) of the function shows up. In any case, it looks a little difficult to figure that out at first glance for somethings that seemed straightforward